# UL don't stay containing in nav

Tags: html, css

I have this pice of code

```
<nav id="nav-main">
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
```

all content id menu should be contain nav, but it isn't already when i checking it in console.

I tried with clear:both, but no changs, full css is in fiddle preview

[jsfiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/3vzext9q/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason the `ul` is being taken out of the flow (and it looks like the `nav` isnt wrapping the `ul` is because the `ul` has `position:absolute;`.

Remove `position:absolute;` from your `ul` and the menu looks and works the same but the `nav` element now wraps it